Azure Containters WITHOUT Docker Local Install
Edit:  I solved this one.
The example docs say after obtaining the token, log in as such:
docker login ${ACR_NAME}.azurecr.io --username 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --password-stdin <<< $TOKEN
I was looking at the zeros in the username parameter and replacing them with the GUID of my username This was leading me to an obscure Entra ID error which indicated I needed to set up an AppReg to fix this.  I simply needed to use literal ZEROs in the --username parameter..  Too much on my mind this week.  Doh!
Original Question:
I would like to run a vendor provided container in Azure. This would be a 1 hour setup on-prem but is turning out to be a hassle to get this running in our Azure Cloud.
My company doesn't allow public internet access to our cloud resources.  I'll need to set up a 'Azure Container Registry' first, upload my vendor's container to this registry, then set up a 'Azure Container' service and point it at the registry. Easy so far.
To place the container in the 'Container Registry' it appears I need a commercial license for Docker Desktop running on my workstation.  At my company docker is prohibited on workstations (so I would need to requisition something for this simple file copy).  Also, 'Docker Desktop' requires a commercial licence now with it's own terms, which seems overkill when I only want to copy a file from my vendor into an Azure container.  Also I don't want to tie my workstation to this container workflow for updates.
I considered using podman to copy the container (which I use for my normal on-prem work) but the 'az acr login' command appears to specifically look for a locally running 'dockerd'
Another approach - use a token?  Is this a possible approach?
#1 Get a token
SECRET_TOKEN=`az acr login -n mycontainerreg --expose-token --output tsv --query accessToken`

#2 Attempt to authenticate to container registry
echo $SECRET_TOKEN |docker login mycontainerreg.azurecr.io -u 57c0d44e-0000-0000-0000-d00dd00dd00d --password-stdin

#3 Error:
INFO[0001] Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint  error="Get \"https://mycontainerreg.azurecr.io/v2/\": unauthorized: Application not registered with AAD."

Get "https://mycontainerreg.azurecr.io/v2/": unauthorized: Application not registered with AAD. 

I hope someone can recommend an easy way to place this container image file into my Azure container registry!
TIA
-Scott
EDIT

You can install docker-core on Linux and do what ever you need

You can try logging in with the service principal by using below cmds:
az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME -p $AZURE_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT
az acr login --name 

You can check list how to connect or login to ACR in this page
acr page
from your error Azure account that you use don't have access to the ACR service, sometimes it because you don't have access in resources group level
please recheck your account privilege or roles
